# Refer database tables in R

Tags: r

I have a database name Team which has 40 tables . How can I connect to that database and refer to particular table without using sqlquerry. By the use of R data Structures.

Comment: Your question is missing lots of valuable information that would help people answering.
Specifically, which platform (Windows? which version? Linux? OSX?) are you working on? Will the Database run on the same machine where R is deployed? What Database are you using? Which version? What about R? Again, which version?

Comment: I have database in sas enterprise and I want to do all my stuff in R . I am using windows 7 (32 bit) and R (3.1.1). I do not want to use sqlQuerry in R .

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean with "*How can I connect to that database and refer to particular table without using sqlquerry*".

I am not aware of a way to "see" DB tables as R dataframes or arrays or whatever without importing the tuples first through some sort of query (in SQL) - this seems to be the most practical way to use R with DB data (without going to the hassle of exporting these as .csv files first, and re-read them in R).

There are a couple ways to import data from a DB to R, so that the *result of a query* becomes a R data structure (including proper type conversion, ideally).

- Here is a [short guide on how to do that with SQL-R](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~nolan/stat133/Fall05/lectures/SQL-R.pdf)
- A similar [brief introduction to the DBI family](http://www.slideshare.net/jeffreybreen/accessing-databases-from-r)

Comment: I am facing with one difficulty in R.  I am unable to connect to a database residing on a netezza server using  RODBC package in R.
I have the database name ,server name and credentials to connect. 
But when using RODBC package the command odbcDriverConnect needs some parameters such as driver and so on.

Comment: @pratik-kumar-chhapolika : have you seen this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22302411/connect-r-and-netezza-using-rjdbc