# sqldf package catch rows in R

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, sqldf

guys ,i have a question since i input my excel sheet as data frame
my data is shown as below

```
arr=as.data.frame(rbindlist(df,fill=T))
> arr
    ST Code Emp          Employee              Pay.Code Hours     Gross
1   AL 7229  65                 S                HOURLY  0.00      0.00
2   AL 7229  65                 S                SALARY  0.00   3060.00
3   AL 7229  65                 S              PER DIEM  0.00    765.00
4   AL 7229  65                 S EXPENSE REIMBURSEMENT  0.00     11.00
5   AL 7229   2                 R                HOURLY 60.00    720.00
6   CA   42   2                 R              OVERTIME  3.25     58.50
7   CA   42   3                 A                HOURLY 80.00    800.00
8   CA   42   3                 A              OVERTIME  6.25     93.75
9   CA   42   4                 N                HOURLY 79.25    990.63
10  CA   42   4                 N              OVERTIME  7.00    131.25
11  CA   42   9                 P                HOURLY 32.00    352.00
12  CA   42   9                 P              OVERTIME  1.75     28.88
13  CA   42  10                 E                HOURLY 72.00    864.00
14  CA   42  10                 E              OVERTIME  5.00     90.00
15 AL  7229  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA  23954.00
16 AL  7229  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA  11092.10
17  GA 7380  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA  98142.00
18  GA 8380  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA  11984.00
19  NC 7380  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA 218129.00
20  NC 8380  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA  27891.00
21  TN 7380  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA  28441.00
22  TN 8380  NA              <NA>                  <NA>    NA   8348.00
```

i use

```
outcome=sqldf("select * from arr where ST = 'AL'")
outcome
```

always get

```
 ST Code Emp          Employee              Pay.Code Hours Gross
1 AL 7229  65                S                HOURLY     0     0
2 AL 7229  65                S                SALARY     0  3060
3 AL 7229  65                S              PER DIEM     0   765
4 AL 7229  65                S EXPENSE REIMBURSEMENT     0    11
5 AL 7229   2                R                HOURLY    60   720
```

i always cannot catch  15 & 16
where did it go wrong ?

Comment: It appears to be that they are `"AL "` (note the space). Either fix your data (preferable) or make a more flexible sql statement: `select * from arr where ST like 'AL%'` (untested).

Comment: thanks r2evans it wworks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I know the wrong pattern I usually try to normalize all the data before.

In your case, remove the blank spaces will solve the problem.

`arr$ST = strsplit(arr$ST," ")[[1]]
 arr$ST = arr$ST[arr$ST!=""]`

But if you don't know the wrong pattern you can use Regex, i'm not sure if sqldf is able to regex pattern (I never used sqldf before, sorry), but if is you can use the regex pattern from SQL language.

Ps.:

1 - You can filter the data without sqldf using `arr[which(arr$ST == "AL"),]`

2 - Don't forget to save your data before any changes.

Comment: The question is not whether `sqldf` does regex, it's whether SQL does regex. And it depends on the db-engine being used by `sqldf` at the moment. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33029814/3358272. (The default use of SQLite means no regex is available.)