# If Column contains "-" at the end of a value, remove the "-" at the end - sqldf

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have a dataframe like below:

```
    ColA    ColB
   djdn-       3
   dn-dn       5
   ndmc-       8
nd-nd-md       9
```

Expected Output:

```
    ColA    ColB   New_Col
   djdn-       3      djdn
   dn-dn       5     dn-dn
   ndmc-       8      ndmc
nd-nd-md       9  nd-nd-md
```

Using sqldf, I want to remove the "-" at the end of the value if it exists at the end.

This is my attempted code:

```
library(sqldf)
df_new<- sqldf("select CASE(RIGHT([ColA], 1) = '-', LEFT([ColA], LEN([ColA])-1), 
[ColA]) [New_Col] from df")

Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error
```

Comment: Please edit the question to specify (maybe with a tag) which RDBMS you are querying.

Comment: `gsub("-$", "", txt)`

Comment: thanks @M-M it needs to be in sqldf unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you looking for `rtrim`

```
library(sqldf)
df_new<- sqldf("select ColB,rtrim(ColA,'-') as ColA from df")
  ColB     ColA
1    3     djdn
2    5    dn-dn
3    8     ndmc
4    9 nd-nd-md
```

Comment: That will remove *all* consecutive ‘-’ characters (zero, one, three, seventeen, any amount) from the right end of the value. That's different from what the question asks; I don't know whether that matters. @nak5120 does that change the answer?

Answer (score 1):

While using `rtrim` seems easier, here's a solution using `substr`: 
sqldf uses SQLite, which does not have the `RIGHT` or `LEFT` function, so use the `SUBSTR` function instead, and the `LEN` function is `LENGTH`.

```
library(sqldf)
df_new <- sqldf("select df.*, 
               CASE 
                WHEN substr(ColA, length(ColA),1) = '-' THEN substr(ColA, 1, length(ColA)-1) 
               ELSE ColA
               END AS New_Col from df")
```

Comment: Question: does `sqldf` supports `REGEXP`?

Comment: I haven’t tried to use regex in sqldf, but the question has been asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33026213/regarding-sqldf-package-regexp-function?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe it's time for a major update of `sqldf`

Answer (score 0):

To match “value contains ‘-’ at the end”, use (I'll assume PostgreSQL) a [pattern match](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE):

```sql
SELECT
    col_a
FROM df
WHERE (col_a LIKE '%-')
```

Then, to get the value without its final character (which you now know is a ‘-’ character), use a [string manipulation function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html):

```sql
SELECT
    left(col_a, -1) AS col_a_truncated
FROM df
WHERE (col_a LIKE '%-')
```

Comment: I get the same error unfortunately - this was my new code based on your answer - `df2<- sqldf("SELECT left([col_a], -1) AS col_a_truncated FROM df WHERE ([col_a] LIKE '%-")` Error is `Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : near "(": syntax error`